# Remove new lines but not if included within text boundaries

Tags: regex

I have multiple text sections like this:

```
<par>
<button width="2in" maxlines="1">
<code event="onClick" for="web">
<javascript>doClose();
doRemove();
doNotify();</javascript>
</code>Close</button>
</par>
<par>
<button width="2in" maxlines="1">
<code event="onClick" for="web">
<javascript>doClose();
doRun();</javascript>
</code>Run</button>
</par>
```

I want to remove any new line that exists within the `<button>` element but not if it is within the a `<javascript>` element. The outcome I am looking for is this:

```
<par>
<button width="2in" maxlines="1"><code event="onClick" for="web"><javascript>doClose();
doRemove();
doNotify();</javascript></code>Close</button>
</par>
<par>
<button width="2in" maxlines="1"><code event="onClick" for="web"><javascript>doClose();
doRun();</javascript></code>Run</button>
</par>
```

Can this be done with a single regEx?

Reason: The issue here is that because within the `<button>` element's `text()` there are new lines (for example right after the `<button>` start tag), the "label" of the `<button>` elements is calculated as "\nClose" and "\nRun". So I want to eliminate the new lines in the  text() but leave other new lines (line in the `<javascript>` element) intact.

Now that I am looking at this a bit closer, maybe what I am looking for is to eliminate just the new line right after the `<button>` start tag. Hmmm

(I am using java)

Comment: Use DOM, XPath, and maybe xslt. Regex is a really bad choice for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Thanks for the reply. My input file is output from DOM manipulation. I have no control on that process. I am trying to correct the issue in order to import that file to another system. I doubt that XSLT can remove \n but not sure. Re-parse the file sound a bit too much but it might be the solution. It looks like a replace regEx like this should do it for now: (<button.*>)\r\n(<) replace with $1$2 but maybe there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: Why does re-parsing the file sound like a bit too much? Are you not comfortable with DOM, XPath, and xslt?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus difficult to explain the whole project but in general, these replacements are user configurable. The tool I am working on is too generic to use DOM to correct issues hardcoded in the source code. Users (system users/developers) provide replacements they want in configuration files and the tool makes the replacements. RegEx is the easy way to allow input from the user. So the user specifies: RegEx: (<button.*>)\r\n(<)  ReplaceWith: $1$2 and the program does the rest. It can be done with DOM but for my case it looks like RegEx is a better option. Hopefully this explains things a bit